# вопрос про mod_pagespeed

Tags: apache

Я не так давно начал "сисадминить", опыта у меня мало, поэтому у меня есть немного примитивный вопрос.

Я хочу установить на свой веб сервер google pagespeed, сам сервер сделан на связке apache+nginx (nginx как прокси фронт-енд), так вот в моей ситуации, mod pagespeed мне нужно устанавливать для nginx или для apache?

Answer (score 0):

Для nginx, так как именно он работает как фронт и отдаёт статику.